# I need to convert this string into a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have this string:

```
? i.iaaa.iaaa aii.aai.iaaa ia.iiii.i   aiai.aii.iaaa aii.iiii.i   aiai.iaaa.i i.i aii.iiii.i ia.aai.i   aii.iiii.i aii.aai.iaaa aiii.ii.iaaa   , aiii.iiii.i aiii.iiai.i aiii.iiai.i i.ii.iaaa i.i
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[['?'] ['i','iaaa','iaaa'],['aii','aai','iaaa'],['ia','iiii','i'],[' '],['aiai','aii','iaaa'],['aii','iiii','i'],[' '],['aiai','iaaa','i'],['i','i'],['aii','iiii','i'],['ia','aai','i'],[' '],['aii','iiii','i'],['aii','aai','iaaa'],['aiii','ii','iaaa'],[' '],[','],['aiii','iiii','i'],['aiii','iiai','i'],['aiii','iiai','i'],['i','ii','iaaa'],['i','i']
```

To put it in a nutshell:
The points between the a's and i's should be deleted.
The other punctuation marks should be in their own nested list.
a and i combinations from one space to another should be in a nested list together.
If there are several spaces it should be replaced by one space in a list

I already tried:

```
et=input('Enter message here: \n')
#declaration of variables
pt=[]
i=0
#convert string to list
for i in range(0,len(et)):
    if et[i] == '.' and et[i+1] == 'a' or 'i':
        pass
    elif et[i] == 'a' or 'i' and et[i-1] == 'a' or 'i':
        pt[-1]= pt[-1] + et[i]
    else:
        pt.append(list(et[i]))

print(pt)
```

It's not working. The output is:

```
[]
```

Comment: `result = [i.split(".") for i in s.split()]`?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? question contains desired and expected behavior and existing attempt. Seems like a good question?

Comment: @Rakesh That skips every *space*. OP mentioned *If there are several spaces it should be replaced by one space in a list*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
x='? i.iaaa.iaaa aii.aai.iaaa ia.iiii.i   aiai.aii.iaaa aii.iiii.i   aiai.iaaa.i i.i aii.iiii.i ia.aai.i   aii.iiii.i aii.aai.iaaa aiii.ii.iaaa   , aiii.iiii.i aiii.iiai.i aiii.iiai.i i.ii.iaaa i.i'
[i.split('.') for i in x.replace(' ','|').replace('|||','| |').split('|')]
```

---

Output:

```
[['?'],
 ['i', 'iaaa', 'iaaa'],
 ['aii', 'aai', 'iaaa'],
 ['ia', 'iiii', 'i'],
 [' '],
 ['aiai', 'aii', 'iaaa'],
 ['aii', 'iiii', 'i'],
 [' '],
 ['aiai', 'iaaa', 'i'],
 ['i', 'i'],
 ['aii', 'iiii', 'i'],
 ['ia', 'aai', 'i'],
 [' '],
 ['aii', 'iiii', 'i'],
 ['aii', 'aai', 'iaaa'],
 ['aiii', 'ii', 'iaaa'],
 [' '],
 [','],
 ['aiii', 'iiii', 'i'],
 ['aiii', 'iiai', 'i'],
 ['aiii', 'iiai', 'i'],
 ['i', 'ii', 'iaaa'],
 ['i', 'i']]
```

Comment: I don´t really understand it. No problem there. But it works perfectly fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned elsewhere the correct way to tackle a problem like this is either by using .split() and .join() and .replace() on strings and lists, or using regex. For the sake of completeness, here is an answer that based on your attempt.

The primary error made is trying to use shortcuts in boolean logic. In natural language, when we say "the apple is green and round" what we mean is that the apple is green and the apple is round. In coding, we must say this explicitly. For example, the following:

```
if item[i] == "a" or "b"
```

Python will ask whether

```
item[i] == "a"
```

is true and then ask whether

```
"b"
```

is true. Since "b" is a string and has a value, it will always be considered to be True in Python. As a result, this:

```
if item[i] == "a" or "b"
```

is always true. What you want is this:

```
if item[i] == "a" or item[i] == "b"
```

or more succinctly:

```
if item[i] in ("a", "b")
```

Also note that and takes precedence over or. If you want or to take precedence, you gotta add parentheses.

Aside from that, I think that you were too optimistic in trying to solve this with list index checking, but not adding a sublist variable to track.

```
# Please please please give variables names.
inputted = input('Enter message here: \n')


# This is Python. Variables don't need to be declared.
# The list declarations here are only because I actually want to initialise them (so that I can append to the empty list).
# But i=0 is entirely redundant.
result = []
sublist = []

#convert string to list  (this comment is a bit useless. to convert a string to a list you just type list(your_string). What you are doing is somthing else)

for i in range(len(inputted)):  # The starting index will default to 0, and it isn't against PEP 8 to use this implicit behaviour, because it is so common and well understood.

    # Notice the boolean logic syntax.
    if inputted[i] == '.' and (inputted[i+1] == 'a' or inputted[i+1]=='i'):
        # Start a new item in the sublist
        sublist.append('')

    elif inputted[i] == 'a' or inputted[i] == 'i':
        # add to last entry in sub list.
        try:
            sublist[-1] = sublist[-1] + inputted[i]
        # The first time you try do this, there is nothing to append to.
        except IndexError:
            sublist = [inputted[i]]
    # Here we check for multiple whitespaces, but if there are multiple whitespace, 
    # we also want to know that we haven't already added one.
    elif inputted[i] == ' ' and inputted[i+1] == ' ' and sublist != [' ']:
        # multiple whitespace. add whitespace sublist.
        if sublist:
            result.append(sublist)
        sublist = [' ']

    # Single whitespace. start a new sublist
    elif inputted[i] == ' ':
        if sublist:
            result.append(sublist)
        sublist = []

    # punctuation
    else:
        sublist = [inputted[i]]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of solving that, using [groupby method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from itertools.

```
from itertools import groupby

separator = ' '

groups = groupby(data, lambda key: key == separator)

result = []
for is_separator, group in groups:
    # Group is an iterator over every character in that group
    # Convert it into str
    group_str = ''.join(group)

    if is_separator:
        # Skip the group, if it's made out of one separator
        if len(group_str) > 1:
            result.append(list(separator))
    else:
        result.append(group_str.split('.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with regex?

```
import re
def main():
    test = "? i.iaaa.iaaa aii.aai.iaaa ia.iiii.i aiai.aii.iaaa aii.iiii.i aiai.iaaa.i i.i aii.iiii.i ia.aai.i aii.iiii.i aii.aai.iaaa aiii.ii.iaaa , aiii.iiii.i aiii.iiai.i aiii.iiai.i i.ii.iaaa i.i"
    rgx = r"^(\?)|(?:i|a)+|(\s+)"
    result = re.finditer(rgx, test, re.MULTILINE)

    for matchNum, match in enumerate(result, start=1):
        print("["+str(matchNum)+"] = " + match.group() + ",")
main()
```

Then the result is:

```
[1] = ?, [2] =  , [3] = i, [4] = iaaa, [5] = iaaa, [6] =  , [7] = aii, [8] = aai, [9] = iaaa, [10] =  , [11] = ia, [12] = iiii, [13] = i, [14] =  , [15] = aiai, [16] = aii, [17] = iaaa, [18] =  , [19] = aii, [20] = iiii, [21] = i, [22] =  , [23] = aiai, [24] = iaaa, [25] = i, [26] =  , [27] = i, [28] = i, [29] =  , [30] = aii, [31] = iiii, [32] = i, [33] =  , [34] = ia, [35] = aai, [36] = i, [37] =  , [38] = aii, [39] = iiii, [40] = i, [41] =  , [42] = aii, [43] = aai, [44] = iaaa, [45] =  , [46] = aiii, [47] = ii, [48] = iaaa, [49] =  , [50] =  , [51] = aiii, [52] = iiii, [53] = i, [54] =  , [55] = aiii, [56] = iiai, [57] = i, [58] =  , [59] = aiii, [60] = iiai, [61] = i, [62] =  , [63] = i, [64] = ii, [65] = iaaa, [66] =  , [67] = i, [68] = i
```

You can, also, use this tool [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to build the regex as you need.